# Vue invalid CSS - expected 1 selector or at-rule,

Tags: vue.js, sass

I'm trying to `npm run serve` in Vue and receiving the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=sass&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after " ": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
        on line 1 of /Users/MatthewBell/GitHub/pollify/client/src/App.vue
>>  {

   ^
```

Clearly it says the error is in `App.vue` and seems like a misplaced curly brace.

But if check in that file there aren't even any curly braces there:

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="nav">
            <router-link to="/">Home</router-link>|
            <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
        </div>
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass">
#app
    @extend %global-styles
</style>
```

..And the file of class being extended.. `main.sass` is shown below. None of the imported sass sheets have curly braces either, so I'm sitting here very confused about the error message.

```
// Importing all our globally accessible stylesheets
@import ./reset
@import ./variables
@import ./mixins_and_placeholders

%global-styles
    font-family: $font
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
    background-color: $grey-3
    color: $text-black
```

I also searched this question on StackOverflow and some people seem to say it can be an issue with your config file, but I cant find any issues with my `vue.config.js`:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            // pass options to sass-loader
            // @/ is an alias to src/
            // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.sass`
            // Note: this option is named as "data" in sass-loader v7
            sass: {
                prependData: `
                @import "@/styles/main.sass"
                `
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This was working fine before so it's not an issue with the prepend data path.

Comment: Could be that massive indent on your `prependData` `@import` statement. I don't know Sass very well but indents are significant, right?

Comment: @Phil amazing catch - I didn't make the connection that that indent would matter in the config file. That was the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Phil, you should really add that as an answer. Some might argue it's just a typo, but I would argue it's a subtle bug with the tendency to eat up a lot of debugging time, as many developers don't realize tick-quoting preserves indentation.

Comment: @tao I think it would be better if OP answered then. TBH, I'd spend longer trying to figure out what it _should_ be (does it need a newline, etc) whereas OP has already solved it

Comment: @tao I've gone ahead and added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Phil mentioned in the comments. The indented `@import "@/styles/main.sass"` in my config file `vue.config.js` was causing the issue, since backticks preserve indentation. The following syntax solves it:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            // pass options to sass-loader
            // @/ is an alias to src/
            // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.sass`
            // Note: this option is named as "data" in sass-loader v7
            sass: {
                prependData: `@import "@/styles/main.sass"`
            }
        }
    }
};
```